# Angular ngFor and dividing table to titled sections

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following JSON response from the server:

```
stuff = [
   {
      "_id":"59080892c88561d46736a18d",
      "name":"Miscellaneous settings",
      "priority":45,
      "settings":[
         {
            "_id":"590819cc30ae0618902c0a91",
            "token":"Setting 1",
            "value":8096,
            "description":"This is a setting.",
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5908087bc88561d46736a18b",
      "name":"System settings",
      "priority":30,
      "settings":[
         {
            "_id":"590816e697307f345c235360",
            "token":"Another setting",
            "value":65535,
            "description":"This is a test value for whatever reason",
            "level":5
         },
         {
            "_id":"5908175856e60a345475ae21",
            "token":"Third setting",
            "value":32767,
            "description":"This is because why not",
            "level":4
         },
         {
            "_id":"590817b7a2f9262c748542d4",
            "token":"Setting again",
            "value":16535,
            "description":"This is another setting again",
            "level":5
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see, these are simple settings arranged into setting groups. I have to display them as a table, divided into groups.

This is exactly why we have `ngFor`, but there seems to be a problem. I can do this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" *ngFor="let data of stuff">

    <caption>{{ data.name }}</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Token</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Explanation</th>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let setting of data.settings">
            <td>{{ setting.token }}</td>
            <td>{{ setting.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ setting.description }}</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

And it indeed works: it displays the setting group names in `<caption>` tags, and lists the settings in individual groups in a `table` after each.

The problem is that it creates a new `table` for every setting group, because the `ngFor` can only be added to the `table` tag. Every table created this way will have different column widths, and the result looks terrible.

[image]

How can I make `ngFor` work inside the `table`, not repeating the `table`, but only its contents? It would need some HTML tag to encapsulate the content, but I can't use anything which is not a table element. And I wouldn't like to use `colgroup` and inline styles to force the columns to fixed width because that'd mess up responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move ngFor from table level to `ngTemplate`. After that mimic caption with another "colspanned" `td`. You might want to style it a little to match real caption styles:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <ng-template ngFor let-data [ngForOf]="stuff">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5" class="caption">{{ data.name }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Token</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th class="tablecol-700">Explanation</th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let setting of data.settings">
          <td>{{ setting.token }}</td>
          <td>{{ setting.value }}</td>
          <td>{{ setting.description }}</td>
          <td class="tablecol-700">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </ng-template>
  </table>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzcmCE9AwBoWnloKXr9u?p=preview

Comment: This seems to be it, however it throws an error for me: "let-" is only supported on template elements.

Comment: So use `template` instead of `ng-template`. Your version of Angular doesn't have `NgTemplate` yet which will replace `<template>` in version 5.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/pPwEgK)

just move the table repeater to level down to tbody it will not create new table

```
<div ng-app="angularTypeahead">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<table class="table table-striped" >
<tbody ng-repeat="data in stuff">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"> 
  <div class="caption">{{ data.name }}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Token</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th class="tablecol-700">Explanation</th>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="setting in data.settings">
            <td>{{ setting.token }}</td>
            <td>{{ setting.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ setting.description }}</td>
            <td class="tablecol-700"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the old AngularJS, not Angular.

Comment: just replace ng-repeat with ngFor

Comment: <table class="table table-striped" >
<tbody *ngFor="let data of stuff">
....
<tr *ngFor="let setting of data.settings">
            <td>{{ setting.token }}</td>
....

Comment: in this old AngularJS and Angular has no difference

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile the same answer arrived.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your `*ngFor` in your `tbody` since you can have more than one tbody. **But** you can only have 1 caption. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp)

> You can specify only one caption per table.

Here's the code I modified

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Token</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Explanation</th>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  *ngFor="let data of stuff">
        <tr *ngFor="let setting of data.settings">
            <td>{{ setting.token }}</td>
            <td>{{ setting.value }}</td>
            <td>{{ setting.description }}</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, unfortunately the titles are needed.

Comment: I see. Other answers have work around for your requirement using divs inside your table

Comment: So far the best solution is using table-layout: fixed; and then using colgroup. But that's not nice.